# Correct way to get average price

Tags: average

probably a basic question for a lot of you guys, but it was a subject of a friendly debate at my work earlier - needless to say none of the involved were accountants. In short, we are thinking about which is the proper way to get the average price of a sold item. Here is a simple example:

I sell part xyz 3 times this month.

```
I sell 100 for $67 each for $6700
I sell 80 at $70 each for $5600
and I sell 60 at $72 each for $4320
```

Is the average price of the product 69.67 ((67+70+72)/3)?

Or is it 69.25 (6700+5600+4320)/(100+80+60)?

Minor, I know, but still.

Is this just one of those things that you can say "it depends on how look at it". I tend to think it is the latter simply because it seems more accurate, you are actually figuring in all the individual items sold.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is the latter. It is also called weighted average/mean.

See here for some more details.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Weighted_arithmetic_mean

Comment: ahh yes, weighted average - stats classes coming back to me now.(I knew it)

Answer (score 3):

Your friends argument is like saying on an exam, the scores of a class is 1,1,1,1,1,1,5, average is 3.

think of your prices as 67, 67,..., 67, 70, ... 70, 72, 72,... 72, multiplication just saves you adding 240 numbers by hand...

Answer (score 1):

The latter is better, because it actually tells you that what you have earned is the same as if you've sold all the items at this average price.